# How to create PDF using iTextSharp in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

Can anyone tell me how to use iTextSharp.text in asp.net for creating the PDF file, but heading, font size should be as per our needs?

Comment: Please read https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version for more info and examples.

Answer (score -1):

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25f, 20f, 20f, 10f);

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
    Phrase phrase = null;
    PdfPCell cell = null;
    Color color = null;
    pdfDoc.Open();

    int columns = grdGridPrint.Columns.Count;
    // Table and PdfTable classes removed in version 5.XXX
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columns);
    // table.TotalWidth = 500f;
    phrase = new Phrase();

    phrase.Add(new Chunk("Heading in PDF \n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 14, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));

    phrase.Add(new Chunk("\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 6, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
    cell = ClsPDF.PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfCell.CHUNK;

    // table.AddCell(cell);
    cell.Colspan = 7;
    // Colspan for Giving Spaces to Heading if you have to show data in grid of 10 columns that time Colspan =10 
    table.AddCell(cell);
    //table.HeaderRows = 1;
    iTextSharp.text.Font fontTable = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
    // padding can only be set for cells, __NOT__ PdfPTable object
    int padding = 2;
    float[] widths = new float[columns];
    for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
    {
        widths[x] = (float)grdGridPrint.Columns[x].ItemStyle.Width.Value;
        string cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(grdGridPrint.HeaderRow.Cells[x].Text);
        // Cell and Color classes are gone too
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, fontTable))
        {

        };
        table.AddCell(cell);
    }
    // next two lines set the table's __ABSOLUTE__ width
    table.SetTotalWidth(widths);
    table.LockedWidth = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < grdGridPrint.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (grdGridPrint.Rows[i].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                string cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(grdGridPrint.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text);
                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, fontTable))
                {
                    Padding = padding
                };
                //if (i % 2 != 0)
                //{
                //    //cell.BackgroundColor = new System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C2D69B");

                //}
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }
        }
    }

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    pdfDoc.Add(table);
    pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: I am down-voting this answer because you are promoting the use of the old version of iText: iText 5 or earlier. That version is being phased out. It will no longer be supported in the near future. The latest version of iText, is iText 7, and there's a jump-start tutorial on how to use iText 7 here: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version

Comment: But the code I promoted is working fine. I was facing same problem hence posted here but I  don't why people taking otherwise for same.

Comment: Because it's not future proof. Development on iText 5 will stop. If people want a new feature (e.g. they need support for PDF 2.0) and they have started working with iText 5, they will need to throw away their iText 5 code and start anew from scratch writing iText 7 code because iText 5 will never support PDF 2.0. Do you understand my point of view? It's like selling 500 or 1000 rupee bank notes, knowing that they might be useless in the near future.

Comment: I am flagging this answer because *This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.*